# Labelling website as optimized

Tags: seo, local-seo, optimization, website-promotion

I have done my work as a webmaster aggressively in the past. From time to time, I use my old phone to use the internet, and the newest sites never work on my phone (which I can't be surprised of), but my site runs on every phone. I think about everyone. I'm sorry owners of commodore, I haven't supported your system.

But anyways I want to somehow create something of some sorts on my website that will allow search engines and other website data collectors to understand that my website is fast and compatible with nearly everything. Many websites today are geared to work with only newer browsers.

I understand there are tools like Google page-speed insights and webpagetest.org but I used all of those to test my site and to help me make it fast.

I'm willing to add a line of extra HTML in my code or even a special HTTP header if that helps search engines recognize my site more.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do to tell all search engine bots out there that my site is backward compatible with older browsers?

Comment: Having a website that works with old phones will not improve your SEO as such because modern bots render sites, older sites do not render and they simply scan the HTML, completely ignoring the CSS... so catering for older browsers has not affect on the SEO.

Comment: Search engines don't allow you to label your own stuff generally.   They only trust what they can measure.   That is why Google stopped using meta keywords.  Webmasters were putting in keywords saying "you should rank me for this totally unrelated random thing."   Very spammy.  Search engines have learned that you just can't trust many webmasters to keep meta data correct and spam-free.

Comment: I understand that search engines don't appreciate adding spammy sites to their database, but with google, I see advertisements appear before relevant websites on some queries. What I'm trying to say is if a website is super fantastic in terms of speed and compatibility and the general public isn't recognizing it, then search engines should offer these people a hand by promoting these websites by listing them first  to recognize the hard work the webmasters produced instead of always listing their own advertising first.

Comment: I'm gonna feel sorry for people out there that can't afford to upgrade their computers to new technology. I'm talking about people with pentium 1 or even a 486. I searched google for "list websites compatible with older computers" and sadly, it wouldn't print a list directly in its results: https://www.google.ca/search?q=list+websites+compatible+with+older+computers&num=50&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&oq=list+websites+compatible+with+older+computers&gs_l=heirloom-serp.3...24290.25387.1.25763.5.4.1.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.34.heirloom-serp..6.2.187.Zz8mCtEo8lc

Comment: What I was hoping for a list was a list of links, one to each site, but instead, the best it could do was link me to a site updated in 2013 that lists the sites on that page. I mean if google wants to run the web, they should provide the users exactly what they want regardless of the computer system used, not make users hop from page to page to page to find what they want.

Comment: @Mike If it's so easy, you go ahead and make your own search engine which does that and blindly trusts websites that say they're compatible with whatever. Honestly this whole question is silly.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the modern search engines care about "older" phone compatibility.  If the site is mobile-friendly in modern terms, the spiders will detect that and search engines that report it, will.

I suppose you could waste your meta description and/or the opening sentence of text on the site to declare that you are backwards compatible with Nokia flip phones but I'm not at all sure this is a wise thing to do.

tl;dr Don't worry about it.

Comment: For the longest time, I took that "Don't worry about it", but I feel somehow something has to be done because the excellent material is hard to find. Heck, in my other field of work, trying to find material on the internet is almost like trying to find the winning lottery numbers.

Comment: If "don't worry about it" isn't acceptable, how about "it doesn't matter" in re: my first paragraph :)  If your site is well-built (and it sounds like it is) and the material is organized logically and exposed to spiders correctly, it will rank or not rank according to the true value of the information. Things like speed and mobile compatibility add some value but its not the end-all-be-all of SEO.